# Blocking application on startup only means blocking application?

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-webflux, datastax, blocking

It is a well known fact Spring Webflux applications should not be blocking applications.

Was just wondering, is the app considered as blocking application, if there is a blocking call on start up, but no blocking call on business logic? Just a general question.

I have an example, (super easy to reproduce) where I am using Blockhound in order to test if the app is blocking.
While instantiating Bloudhound in my unit and integration tests, the flow has been proven non blocking (very happy).

However, with a Blockhound instantiated on start up, Spring Webflux + **Reactive** Cassandra like this:

```
package com.webflux.question.blockingg;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import reactor.blockhound.BlockHound;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    static {
        BlockHound.install();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }

}


(the Cassandra parts)
package com.webflux.question.blockingg.configuration;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.config.EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories;
import org.springframework.lang.NonNull;

@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
    private String passPhrase;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    private String keyspace;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.datacenter}")
    private String datacenter;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactPoints;
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
    private int    port;

    @Bean
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
        final CqlSessionFactoryBean cqlSessionFactoryBean = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setKeyspaceName(keyspace);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setLocalDatacenter(datacenter);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPort(port);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setUsername(username);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPassword(passPhrase);
        return cqlSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keyspace;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getLocalDataCenter() {
        return datacenter;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected String getContactPoints() {
        return contactPoints;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

}
```

The pom:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.webflux.question</groupId>
    <artifactId>blocking</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>blockhound</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I am seeing below on start up.

Does it means my app is blocking?

Will the event loop be hurt because of this?

Is there a way to workaround this?

Thank you for your time.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error instantiating class AtomicTimestampGenerator (specified by advanced.timestamp-generator.class): Blocking call! java.io.FileOutputStream#writeBytes
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.Reflection.buildFromConfig(Reflection.java:239)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.Reflection.buildFromConfig(Reflection.java:94)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.context.DefaultDriverContext.buildTimestampGenerator(DefaultDriverContext.java:368)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:55)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.context.DefaultDriverContext.getTimestampGenerator(DefaultDriverContext.java:743)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession$SingleThreaded.init(DefaultSession.java:349)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession$SingleThreaded.access$1100(DefaultSession.java:300)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.lambda$init$0(DefaultSession.java:146)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.run(PromiseTask.java:106)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultEventLoop.run(DefaultEventLoop.java:54)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileOutputStream#writeBytes
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(FileOutputStream.java)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:354)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.writeToDestination(OutputStreamManager.java:250)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager.writeToDestination(FileManager.java:273)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.writeToDestination(RollingFileManager.java:240)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flushBuffer(OutputStreamManager.java:282)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flush(OutputStreamManager.java:291)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.directEncodeEvent(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:199)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:190)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:181)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.append(RollingFileAppender.java:312)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:543)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:502)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:485)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:460)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2198)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2152)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2135)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2016)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1875)
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger.info(Log4jLogger.java:179)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock.getInstance(Clock.java:35)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.MonotonicTimestampGenerator.buildClock(MonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:109)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.MonotonicTimestampGenerator.<init>(MonotonicTimestampGenerator.java:43)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.time.AtomicTimestampGenerator.<init>(AtomicTimestampGenerator.java:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.Reflection.buildFromConfig(Reflection.java:232)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: post your pom file

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter if the application startup time is blocking. Reading on webflux introduction, it emphasize reactive advantadge at runtime and on handling request. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux

Comment: @ThomasAndolf posted

Comment: well can't help you more, it looks to me that its is performing a block when it needs to create or write to a file, my guess is logging (log4j) but with the information provided, i cant say much more than that. Without debugging its hard to know more.

Comment: Thank you @ThomasAndolf Did you manage to reproduce? It is really just running things literally out of the box, the error should be happening 100% reproducible.

Also, I do not have any log4j package, and same result when I exclude all log4j dependencies

Comment: no i have not reproduced anything since you havn't provided a minimal working example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: minimal working example uploaded @ThomasAndolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official response from Datastax team:

The error is happening when Spring is building the application context, which happens when the application starts. Blocking calls are usually allowed during this phase, even for reactive / non-blocking applications – otherwise, your application would be totally unable to read a config file, for instance – since this is a blocking call.

Actively working on JAVA-2449 right now. I will change Uuids.random() to use non-blocking stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and adding thread predicate making it not detect the Blocking calls. At least below will not error out the blocking calls but will log the trace and details what is actually blocking.

Hope it helps somebody else.

```
static {
    BlockHound
        .install(builder -> { 
          builder.blockingMethodCallback(it -> {
            new Exception(it.toString()).printStackTrace();
          });
        });
}
```